# Add user field in the screen IN407010

Tags: acumatica

I would like to enter another data column in the screen IN407010, but I cannot write in it. The usr column is read-only?

```
protected void TurnoverCalcItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (TurnoverCalcItem)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<TurnoverCalcItemExt.usrConvtonne>(cache, row, true);  
  Base.TurnoverCalcItems.AllowUpdate = true;
  Base.TurnoverCalcItems.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
  Base.TurnoverCalcItems.AllowSelect = true;
  Base.TurnoverCalcItems.Cache.AllowSelect= true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add a calculated field, I think PXFormula attribute on the DAC Ext should be sufficient.

To do this on the DAC level is something I would recommend to use the links below:

For reference I would recommend you going to the T210 course on the OpenUni, download the reference guide or you can even take a look at the Part 4 their use-case is quite similar to yours in my opinion. It can be found at this:https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t210-development-customized-forms-and-master-detail-relationship/

Also going to this link should also help: https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d75dbfeb-65d2-4f73-80cf-d3d5240a807b

Note: check you version of acumatica too.

Comment: Thanks for your return, my first problem is : I want to update the field, but it's a readonly. Thanks Xavier

Comment: Okay looking at the DAC schema browser at http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/dacBrowser/PX.Objects.IN.Turnover/TurnoverCalcItem . It is a Projection from various tables.  Also, most of the projection are usually not enabled i.e. not editable. So i am not sure how would that work in your scenario.